# box-sizing: border-box causing div with padding inside td to have margins, WHY?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-box

I want to make a box with content that is vertically centered, but also scrolls if the content overflows. I can use a table with vertical-align: middle to achieve the vertical centering, but td's can't overflow scroll, so I put a scrolling div inside the td and made it height: 100%. That's fine until I try to give the scrolling div some padding, which makes it too wide for the td so I give it box-sizing: border-box. Then all of a sudden there's a top and bottom margin on the div!

[image]

**WAT!?**

http://codepen.io/jessehattabaugh/pen/GIjiL

There shouldn't be any space between the green line and the red line, but there it is! If you change the padding on the green div the mysterious margin changes. It's as if the height: 100% is actually 100% - padding or something. If you remove padding, or box-sizing: border-box it goes away.

BONUS POINTS: why doesn't FF respect the table's height: 50% rule when Chrome/Saf do?

Update: some are suggesting that border-collapse or border-spacing fixes, but here's what it looks like after I apply those rules to the table; 
[image]
The table cell's red border collapses with the blue table border, but the green div's border still has space above and below it. Maybe try resizing the height of the browser and see what happens.

Comment: What if one nice sunny day codepen closes it's service... how would your question (in this state) be useful for future visitors? please add the code in Question.

Comment: My question explains what I did. The better question is; what if I stop asking questions on StackOverflow because all I ever get is people telling me I'm not asking questions the right way?

Comment: Have you tried to add `border-collapse: collapse;` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `border-collapse: collapse;` hides the blue border. `border-spacing:0;` seems to do the trick and keep all three borders.

Comment: @SpencerMay not in my browsers; Chrome, Saf, FF OSX. What are you using?

Comment: Chrome, IE and FF. I can attach some screenshots if you would like.

Comment: I added a screenshot, when I add border-spacing: and border collapse, all that changes is the small 1px space between the blue and red lines. The big space above and below the green box remains

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is adding space around the table. In Chrome add:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Maybe try `border-collapse: collapse;` like Roko suggested? `border-spacing` is working for me.

Comment: This fixes it for me aswell

Comment: The green line and the red line? I don't care about the space between the red and blue lines.